# CRM 2013: Strange behavior when refreshing form or navigate back by browser's back-button

Tags: javascript, back-button, dynamics-crm-2013, page-refresh

I'm actually implementing Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 for our company.

At the moment we have a strange behavior.
We implemented our own contact search and include it on a dashboard as an IFrame.
When we open a contact from the search result, it shows the contact form.

If I refresh the page by press "F5" it jumps back to the dashboard with the contact search. I expected a refresh of the contact form. This does not happen every time.

Same if I navigate from the contact to an activity. If I press browsers back button, it goes back to customer serach. I espect that it goeas back to the contact form.

Does someone know why this happen?

Cheers

Comment: If you are utilizing JavaScript for your navigation, are you using the `pushState()` method?

Comment: Sorry for my late answer. For navigation to a contact i use a normal link. For navigation from contact to activity it's the normal CRM navigation with double click on a row in a subgrid. But if then the user push the back button of the browser, or refresh the page with "F5" it sometime jumps directly back to our own search. The exptected action is for "back" to jump back on contact form, and for Refresh that the actually open page just refreshes. At the moment we don't use any special javascript for navigation.

Comment: Does the contact record open in the IFrame or in the "whole" browser window? Also, if your right-click on the back button (to see the history) what entries does it show?

Comment: The contact opens in a new window or tab, not in the same window. It's is implemented with window.open not with window.openEntityForm (was a business requirement that it opens i a new window)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem sounds like it could be the URL you are using to open the new window/tab. Since you are using a new window to open your results, the URL should be crafted to open that specific record and use it as a basis for all actions performed in that new window.

Try this:

1. Open an existing CRM contact record (doesn't matter which) in your browser and click the "Email A Link" button.
2. In the email which is generated, copy the URL. It will look something like this: `<CrmUrl>/main.aspx?etc=2&extraqs=formid%3d<FormGUID>&id=%7b<ContactRecordGUID>%7d&pagetype=entityrecord`
3. Update your IFrame results to link to a contact records using the URL template from above. The *only* part you will need to change is the `ContactRecordGUID` part.

Once this is implemented, it should work (I just tested with no issue). You can test it yourself first by creating a new window using the link created from the "Email A Link" function and then navigate around a bit. The back and refresh buttons should work as expected in this new window.

Comment: We use exactly this url for open the contact. My problem is that it sometimes works as expected and sometimes it jumps back on the wrong page. We try also to use the histKey (https://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c7ffbf44-ea9e-43de-a905-cc69bc7faca0/crm-2013-problem-in-record-navigation?forum=crmdevelopment), but the solution does not always work.

Comment: How could it jump back to the search page on your _new_ window? It wouldn't be in the history of that window.

Comment: I don't know why it happens :(

Comment: Can you post an actual URL which your IFrame generates and uses as a link?

Comment: The link at the moment is: http://<server>/<orgname>/main.aspx?etn=contact&pagetype=entityrecord&id=%7B4b5aecfb-b37b-e411-80c4-005056ac4b24%7D&extraqs=histKey%3d65837611%26newWindow%3dtrue%26

Comment: If we open the contact by openEntityForm in the same Window the back button and the refresh work as expected. But at the moment the business requirement is that the contact will be opened in a new window.

Comment: Try this: `etc=2` instead of `etn=contact`. Make sure that is the _only_ parameter before `extraqs`. Drop, the `histKey` (this is probably what is causing the back behavior). Give the format I posted in my answer above a shot - we have been using this for about a year and haven't experienced any of the problems you are.

Comment: It worked now, thank you very much. We take it under close surveilance.